# record still appears after deleting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have deleted a record with EmpID = 13 from HrEmployee table, when I use select query to filter empId=13 then it shows no result, that's good but this query still shows empID=13 records why is this so?

```
SELECT distinct 
dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID, 
dbo.HrEmployee.EmplName, 
dbo.AtdRecord.RecDate, 
dbo.AtdRecord.RecTime, 
dbo.HrDept.DeptName
FROM dbo.HrDept 
inner JOIN dbo.HrEmployee
ON dbo.HrDept.DeptID = dbo.HrEmployee.DeptID 
inner JOIN dbo.AtdRecord 
ON dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID = dbo.AtdRecord.EmplID
where HrEmployee.EmplID = 13
```

Comment: Are you sure you deleted it?  Perhaps a fk constraint to ATDRecord.empid prevented that from happening and you need to delete that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some record still exsits with EmpID = 13 in table `dbo.AtdRecord` and you are using `INNER JOIN` try this:

```
SELECT distinct 
dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID, 
dbo.HrEmployee.EmplName, 
dbo.AtdRecord.RecDate, 
dbo.AtdRecord.RecTime, 
dbo.HrDept.DeptName
FROM dbo.HrDept 
left outer JOIN dbo.HrEmployee
ON dbo.HrDept.DeptID = dbo.HrEmployee.DeptID 
left outer JOIN dbo.AtdRecord 
ON dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID = dbo.AtdRecord.EmplID
where HrEmployee.EmplID = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your data, I would check for EmpID = 13 in the AtdRecord table as well.  Also, try removing the JOIN to HrDept and just query with the HrEmployee and AtdRecord tables. Basically, simplify the query and to determine what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will be linked to your the problem in your other post,
[select statement working unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349391/select-statement-working-unexpectedly/21350871#21350871)

You have two copies of the same table, the original intended table and one in the [master] database.

you are probably running this query against the master database where the record EmpId 13 still exists but you deleted it from the original table