# select statement working unexpectedly

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

when i click SELECT TOP 1000 row from table then it only shows some records like 3 records

[image]

but when i manually run query on same table then it shows all records like many 1000s records which i always want.

```
Select * from dbo.HrEmployee
```

[image]

why ? Help please, i'm using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: Do you have 2 databases and executing these selects on different databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like you have created two copies of the same database, the one is in the “intended” database and the second has been created in the master database. 3 records were then inserted into the intended table and the rest were inserted into the master.dbo.HrEmployee.

When you use the select top 1000 you are running the query against the correct database even though it only has 3 records and when you run the second query you are running it against the same table in Master